# How to change cache polilcy for static assets in React app (created with create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker, create-react-app

I have created an app using React.js (with create-react-app) and I cannot find a way to change the cache policy (I am interested in max-age) for my static assets. By default, the static assets of my app (including when I use the production build with 'npm run build') have a max-age of 0.

All I found in the official create-react-app docs was this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/#static-file-caching

It did not help me change the cache policy for my static assets (I have images).

I also tried using the "fetch" method and setting a custom header, but I ended up having a duplicate value "max-age=99999, max-age=0". It looks like create-react-app bypasses your custom headers when it comes to cache policy.

How do I set a custom header? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If your web server can't set those headers, [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) and [Service Worker patterns](https://serviceworke.rs/) would be your best bet for client-side caching.  Were you also able to review these create-react-app docs?

1. [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)
2. [Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment)

You could also try [using a web server like Nginx to proxy create-react-app](https://www.google.com/search?q=create-react-app%20nginx%20proxy), remove its headers, and add your own:

```
location / {
   ...

   // hide create-react-app response header
   proxy_hide_header max-age;

  // send your own header to client
  add_header max-age 99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to set a standard cache policy through create-react-app out of the box? If not, is the work-around with one of the solutions you posted above going to be easy?

Comment: Not sure of out-of-box possibility because I use load balancers or Nginx in front of Node servers. Updated answer with that suggestion. You could [search/create and official issue/question](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues) with them. They're a very helpful community

Answer (score 0):

Create react app just provides a bundle of static files. It does include a server but it's a dev server (when you run `npm start`). So even if you find a way to adjust that server's configuration, it will have no effect on your deployed app.

When you deploy your app, you serve the static bundle of files that CRA builds when you run `npm run build`. You can even serve that with a static server like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). That server is the one that has the ability to provide Cache-control headers to the client. (If you wanna try locally with `serve`, you can look through the docs and add a server config to include those headers)

So there's nothing you can do in the app code itself to affect the Cache-control headers, that's something you need to configure in whatever server you're using to deploy your app.